# Creating array handles for function that returns vector of polynomial expressions

Tags: matlab, function, handles

I am trying to use the numerical integration function 'integral'

I created a function of four polynomial functions

```
[x; x^2; x^3; x^4]
```

now I want to integrate this vector row by row using the integral function.
I tried making a function handle for the function and passed it to the 'integral' function

```
function f = test(x)
    f = [x,x^2,x^3,x^4];
end
```

However, I get the following error when calling it command line:

```
test_var=@test
integral(test_var,0,1)
Error using  ^ 
One argument must be a square matrix and the other must be a scalar. 
Use POWER (.^) for elementwise power.

Error in test (line 2)
    f = [x,x^2,x^3,x^4];

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
            fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
        [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 75)
    [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral (line 88)
Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation of `integral`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html):

> `q = integral(fun, xmin, xmax)`

1. For a **scalar-valued function** `fun` you need to define the function so that it accepts vector input and produces vector output.

   > For scalar-valued problems, the function `y = fun(x)` must accept a vector argument, `x`, and return a vector result, `y`. This generally means that fun must use array operators instead of matrix operators. For example, use `.*` (`times`) rather than `*` (`mtimes`).
2. If you have a **vector-valued function** `fun` you need to use the input flag `'ArrayValued'`:

   > Set this flag to `true` to indicate that `fun` is a function that accepts a scalar input and returns a vector, matrix, or N-D array output.

   and in that case the requirement in item 1 above is not necessary:

   > If you set the `'ArrayValued'` option to true, then `fun` must accept a scalar and return an array of fixed size.

---

So, you need to **add the input flag `'ArrayValued'`** to indicate that you have a vector-valued function:

```
f = @(x) [x; x^2; x^3; x^4]; % or [x; x.^2; x.^3; x.^4];
integral(f, 0, 1, 'ArrayValued', true) % or integral(@f, 0, 1, 'ArrayValued', true)
                                       % if f is defined in a file
```

gives

```
ans =
   0.500000000000000
   0.333333333333333
   0.250000000000000
   0.200000000000000
```